# SQL Server 2014 with SSMS Generation For Inserts Not Working

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

- SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition SP2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.4

I have seen the feature used - when performing an INSERT - after hitting [ENTER] after the table name - a user should see the fields generated in regards to the table columns - whilst I do not.

I assume it's not an IntelliSense problem. I can use IntelliSense when referencing table names. This generation that should appear when I type is the same as right-clicking table name -> Script Table As -> INSERT TO -> New Query.

I have tried refreshing the cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to no avail. I have manually checked all of the IntelliSense settings and they are enabled. I have ran the Generation scripts Task. This passes.

How can I get this working? It's a good feature, otherwise I need to manually type all of the inserts and respective values manually/right click the table every time.

Comment: I'm guessing that the user had some kind of extension installed; that's not base functionality in SSMS. I'd suggest asking the person who you saw the using the functionality about it.

Comment: You are correct. It is a plugin, one by Redgate. Do you know of any freely available ones offering the same auto completion for INSERT statements?